# how to manage Date interval HOUR in hive

Tags: sql, hiveql

how to manage hour interval in hive, I try this code:

```
select DATE_SUB(current_timestamp(),INTERVAL '1' HOUR);
```

> error return : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:124 cannot recognize input near 'INTERVAL' ''1'' 'HOUR' in select expression

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not how `date_sub()` works in Hive.  And unfortunately, it does not simply support interval arithmetic.

So, unix formats to the rescue!

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp()) - 3600)
```

Of course, you don't need to do the conversion *to* unix time for the current date/time:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 3600)
```